# Unable to install Az modules

Tags: azure, powershell

**When i try running below powershell command on Powershell command prompt:**

Install-Module Az -Force -confirm:$false -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

**Getting Below error:**

WARNING: 'Az' matched module 'Az/4.6.0' from provider: 'PowerShellGet', repository 'PSGallery'.
WARNING: 'Az' matched module 'Az/4.6.0' from provider: 'PowerShellGet', repository 'PSGallery1'.
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to install, multiple modules matched 'Az'. Please specify a single
-Repository.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21

... $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Pa
ckage], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : DisambiguateForInstall,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPa
ckage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VLRa.png)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two repositories that is Matching the Az module you will need to provide which one to use to get the module:

```
Install-Module Az -Force -confirm:$false -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository "PSGallery"
```

Or you can unregister one repository if its a duplicate:

```
Get-PsRepository

Unregister-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery1"
```

Answer (score 0):

switching to TLS 1.2 might help: Run the following command for that and try again installing Az

```
PS C:\> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```